# How to make service worker control the root path of the website?

Tags: javascript, frontend, service-worker

My website is served at `https://xxxxxx.com`, and I set the scope of service worker `sw.js` as `/`, but the result is the service worker can't control the page `https://xxxxxx.com`, other pages are controlled like `https://xxxxxx.com/`, though they are the same one page.
It seems that the scope `/` is the max scope of a service worker, so could you please give some advice to make the service worker can control `https://xxxxxx.com`,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after researching its [W3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#dfn-scope-url) and local testing ( where I deleted the scope declaration ), there's no workaround that I can think of. Every service worker registration needs a scope in order to work properly.

In this case, since `https://xxxxxx.com` and `https://xxxxxx.com/` are the same page, you could redirect users to the latter instead.

Comment: Did you try adding a `Service-Worker-Allowed` http response header to your root page(from the server side obviously)

Comment: @MatJ Thanks for your advice, but it's complicated to add server side support, I'm looking for other ways do not depend on server.